# remove last view

Tags: iphone

I have made one small application. I want to remove last view which is a mapview.

When I click the back button, then last mapview is removed.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on click of back back button write:-

```
NSArray *arr =[self.view subviews];
for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++){
     UIView *vw=[arr objectAtIndex:i];
     if([vw isKindOfClass:[MKMapView class]])
     [vw removeFromSuperview];

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose mMapView is the iboutlet to your mapview.

call this in back button callback.

[mMapView removeFromSuperview];